# How to use only matchers at the stubs without applying body?

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I am confused about behavior of body and bodyMatchers sections.

For example for a contract response.

I want my consumer (stub) to have a body from file (exact response from the stub) and producer only to have some matchers for the response (to validate reponse).

1 case I tried:

```
...
body (
    file('__files/someFile.json')
)
bodyMathers {
    jsonPath('$.[cards[0]].cardType', byRegex('[A-Z]{2}')
}
```

Expected - result:

1. Test has matchers for the reponse - false
2. Test doesn't have body matching - false
3. Stub has response body from the file - true
4. Stub doesn't have matchers - true

---

My workaround for a json body and **response** section:
to add **something for the producer body** or i won't get matchers at the test response:

```
body (
    $(
        consumer(
             file('__files/someFile.json')
        ),
        producer(
            cards: [
                  cardType: anyNonEmptyString()
             ]
        )
    )
)
bodyMathers {
    jsonPath('$.[cards[0]].cardType', byRegex('[A-Z]{2}')
}
```

---

Shortly the problem I see - **bodyMatchers requires body**, but it is not intuitive.
 Response could have only matchers for the producer (tests) and request could have only matchers for the consumer (stubs).

I think it should work like this:

```
body (
    $(
       consumer(
          file('__files/someFile.json')
       )
     )
)
bodyMathers {
    jsonPath('$.[cards[0]].cardType', byRegex('[A-Z]{2}')
}
```

---

**Updated**:

```
request {
body(
               file('__files/offer13-request.xml').asString()
       )
       bodyMatchers {
               xPath('/a/b/c/text()', byRegex('123'))
       }
}
```

And i see at the stubs:

```
{
      "matchesXPath" : {
        "expression" : "/soap:Envelope/@xmlns:soap",
        "equalTo" : "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
      }
    }, {
      "matchesXPath" : {
        "expression" : "/a/b/c/text()",
        "matches" : "123"
      }
    }
```

But i need only my matcher `"expression" : "/a/b/c/text()"`

Answer (score 0):

> I want my consumer (stub) to have a body from file (exact response from the stub) and producer only to have some matchers for the response (to validate reponse).

That's not how it works.

```
body (
    file('__files/someFile.json')
)
bodyMathers {
    jsonPath('$.[cards[0]].cardType', byRegex('[A-Z]{2}')
}
```

Means that

1) you have a body in a file `someFile.json`

2) it will be parsed and each part of the body will be analyzed like described in the json file

3) for th concrete json path there will be a regex verification (only for that json path)

> Shortly the problem I see - bodyMatchers requires body, but it is not intuitive.

Since it's a `bodyMatcher` it requires a body. It kind of makes sense since it's a body matcher. If it was a matcher for headers it would require headers.

Comment: thank you for the response. I understand the meaning of `bodyMatchers` now, but what to do if, for an example: At the request with XML body I want only body matchers at the stub. If I use body + file + bodyMatchers - I get both one at the stubs but I want only the matchers.

Comment: `bodyMatchers` in the request side will always be for the stub

Comment: but how NOT to convert the body to the stubs matchers?

Comment: I can't use bodyMatchers without a body -> I use body -> but I don't need 'exact' values for the stub request part. I need: stub with matchers at the request, test with the exact body at the request. `consumer` / `producer` sections separation doesn't help

Comment: I don't understand your problems, sorry. If for the request side of the contract you use a `bodyMatcher` then on the test side we use the concrete value from the body and in the stub you have the dynamic matching. That's exactly what you want to do.

Comment: please see "Updated" section at the question

Comment: We parse the whole body (in this case XML). If a section is there in the XML then we analyze it. We describe it thouroughly in the documentation, please read it (https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-contract#learn).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194529/discussion-between-artem-ptushkin-and-marcin-grzejszczak).